# Convert query string to seo friendly url but allow others query string

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I have this code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ product.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

I want something like this, URL:
`domain.com/products/product.php?slug=product-name&search=test`
To make it work at this address:
`domain.com/products/product-name?search=test`

Now it's working almost fine, but when I check this in php the *search* query not working:
`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && !empty($_GET['search']))`

Comment: Add `QSA` flag: `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: @anubhava Works fine, thank you!